# How to add the new page using NSIS script in the local folder to create the installer instead of taking it from program files /NSIS

Tags: nsis

I write the NSIS script file that is taking the current locale (in our case it is "English") and generating the installer.

Here, I need to add few more additional functionalities to this.

1. Currently it is taking the pages from the NSIS folder (C:\Program Files\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI 2\Pages)

Here if i want to add my own page to this, how can i do that? Can i create .nsh file locally and use that?

In that case under
; pages
!insertmacro ... Do we need to give the path?

2. Similary for "Language files". For example, If i want to add my own strings to English.nsh file, can i copy it to the local folder? and once added the new strings how to use in the script? Because now by default it is taking it from C:\Program Files\NSIS\Contrib\Language files.
3. And also how to set the specific language (irrespective of the locale) in the "Function .onInit"

Below the Basic code snippet i have used:

```
;NSIS Modern User Interface
;Multilingual Example Script

!pragma warning error all

;--------------------------------
;Include Modern UI

  !include "MUI2.nsh"

;--------------------------------
;General

  ;Properly display all languages (Installer will not work on Windows 95, 98 or ME!)
  Unicode true

  ;Name and file
  Name "Locale Language"
  OutFile "LocaleLanguage.exe"

  ;Default installation folder
  InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\LocaleLanguage"

  ;Get installation folder from registry if available
  InstallDirRegKey HKCU "Software\LocaleLanguage" ""

  ;Request application privileges for Windows Vista
  RequestExecutionLevel user

;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings

  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING

  ;Show all languages, despite user's codepage
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES

;--------------------------------
;Language Selection Dialog Settings

  ;Remember the installer language
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT "HKCU"
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "Software\LocaleLanguage"
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "Installer Language"

;--------------------------------
;Pages

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;Languages

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English" ; The first language is the default language
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "German"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Japanese"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Korean"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Italian"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Dutch"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Danish"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Greek"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Russian"
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Portuguese"

;--------------------------------
;Reserve Files

  ;If you are using solid compression, files that are required before
  ;the actual installation should be stored first in the data block,
  ;because this will make your installer start faster.

  !insertmacro MUI_RESERVEFILE_LANGDLL

;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections

Section "Dummy Section" SecDummy

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

  ;ADD YOUR OWN FILES HERE...

  ;Store installation folder
  WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Locale Language" "" $INSTDIR

  ;Create uninstaller
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Installer Functions

Function .onInit

 ; !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY

FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  ;USE A LANGUAGE STRING IF YOU WANT YOUR DESCRIPTIONS TO BE LANGAUGE SPECIFIC

  ;Assign descriptions to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SecDummy} "A test section."
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END


;--------------------------------
;Uninstaller Section

Section "Uninstall"

  ;ADD YOUR OWN FILES HERE...

  Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

  RMDir "$INSTDIR"

  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Locale Language"

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Uninstaller Functions

Function un.onInit

  !insertmacro MUI_UNGETLANGUAGE

FunctionEnd
```

**UPDATE:**

Below is the updated code using English and Swedish .nsh files.

```
!pragma warning error all

;--------------------------------
;Include Modern UI

  !include "MUI2.nsh"
  !include LogicLib.nsh
  !include nsDialogs.nsh

;--------------------------------
;General

  ;Properly display all languages (Installer will not work on Windows 95, 98 or ME!)
  Unicode true

  ;Name and file
  Name "Locale Language"
  OutFile "LocaleLanguage.exe"

  ;Default installation folder
  InstallDir "$LOCALAPPDATA\LocaleLanguage"

  ;Get installation folder from registry if available
  InstallDirRegKey HKCU "Software\LocaleLanguage" ""

  ;Request application privileges for Windows Vista
  RequestExecutionLevel user

;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings

  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING

  ;Show all languages, despite user's codepage
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES

;--------------------------------
;Language Selection Dialog Settings

  ;Remember the installer language
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_ROOT "HKCU"
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_KEY "Software\LocaleLanguage"
  !define MUI_LANGDLL_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "Installer Language"

;--------------------------------
;Pages
Page Custom mycustompage
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

;--------------------------------
;Languages

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English" ; The first language is the default language
  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Swedish"

;--------------------------------
;Reserve Files

  ;If you are using solid compression, files that are required before
  ;the actual installation should be stored first in the data block,
  ;because this will make your installer start faster.

  !insertmacro MUI_RESERVEFILE_LANGDLL

  ;Including the English and Swedish nsh files from the below path
  !include "E:\prakash\LangTesting\LanguageFiles\English.nsh"
  !include "E:\prakash\LangTesting\LanguageFiles\Swedish.nsh"

;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections

Section "Dummy Section" SecDummy

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

  ;ADD YOUR OWN FILES HERE...

  ;Store installation folder
  WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Locale Language" "" $INSTDIR

  ;Create uninstaller
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

SectionEnd

; To use the strings defined in English.nsh and Swedish.nsh files

!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "$(mypagetitle)"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "$(mypagesubtitle)"
!define MUI_PAGE_DEFAULT_TEXT "$(defaulttext)"

var TextHandle


Function mycustompage
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(mypagetitle) $(mypagesubtitle)
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u "$(defaulttext)"
    Pop $TextHandle
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Installer Functions

Function .onInit

 ; !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
 ;$LANGUAGE
 System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetTickCount()i.r0' ; Get a "random" number
IntOp $0 $0 & 1
${If} $0 <> 0
    StrCpy $Language ${LANG_SWEDISH} ; Force Swedish
${Else}
    !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY ; Let the user choose a language
${EndIf}

FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  ;USE A LANGUAGE STRING IF YOU WANT YOUR DESCRIPTIONS TO BE LANGAUGE SPECIFIC

  ;Assign descriptions to sections
  ;!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN
   ; !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SecDummy} "A test section."
  ;!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END


;--------------------------------
;Uninstaller Section



**********
**English.nsh**

;Language: English (1033)


!insertmacro LANGFILE "English" = "English" =

LangString mypagetitle ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Hello"
LangString mypagesubtitle ${LANG_ENGLISH} "World"


***********
**Swedish.nsh**

;Language: Swedish (1053)

!insertmacro LANGFILE "Swedish" = "Svenska" =

LangString mypagetitle ${LANG_SWEDISH} "Bork"
LangString mypagesubtitle ${LANG_SWEDISH} "borkbork"
LangString defaulttext ${LANG_SWEDISH} "Skriva bork bork..."
LangString defaulttext ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Type something here..."
```

Here, I have created English.nsh and Sweedish.nsh files in my local folder and included those files. And then defined those strings. When I am running it is always showing in "Sweedish". It is not showing in English. Please let me know is it the correct way to proceed? and also any changes required?. Here i commented the ;Descriptions section because it is throwing some errors. Why we need this ;Description section?

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify the NSIS included .NSH files, there is usually a way to override specific things.

You need to use [one](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) of the custom page plug-ins to create a custom page:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
Page Custom mycustompage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE Swedish

LangString ^InstallBtn ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Instaaaaall" ; Override default language string
LangString mypagetitle ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Hello"
LangString mypagesubtitle ${LANG_ENGLISH} "World"
LangString defaulttext ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Type something here..."

LangString mypagetitle ${LANG_SWEDISH} "Bork"
LangString mypagesubtitle ${LANG_SWEDISH} "borkbork"
LangString defaulttext ${LANG_SWEDISH} "Skriva bork bork..."

var TextHandle

!include LogicLib.nsh    
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Function mycustompage
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(mypagetitle) $(mypagesubtitle)
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u "$(defaulttext)"
    Pop $TextHandle
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetTickCount()i.r0' ; Get a "random" number
IntOp $0 $0 & 1
${If} $0 <> 0
    StrCpy $Language ${LANG_SWEDISH} ; Force Swedish
${Else}
    !insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY ; Let the user choose a language
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

You can set the language by writing the language id to `$Language` in `.onInit`. There is also a language selection dialog you can use. The MUI readme shows you how to use LangStrings for the section descriptions...

Comment: Hi Anders,
Can we use separate .nsh files for English and Swedish strings and based on the locale by default can it select the appropriate one?                                                                            

yes, i have seen the example related to language selection dialog. But as per my requirement there is no option of
selecting a language from the dialog. Directly based on the system locale (language) it should display that particular language.

Comment: 1) Yes you can use different .nsh files for different languages if you want (!include just "pastes" the content into your .nsi). Ideally you should save them as UTF-8 with BOM. 2) NSIS already tries to pick the correct language before .onInit (GetUserDefaultUILanguage).

Comment: Hi Anders,  I updated my code (Added in the Updated part of the original post) based on your suggestions and also added separate .nsh files for English and Swedish. When I run it is always showing in Swedish. I am also not sure whether my changes are correct or not. Please suggest.

Comment: Remove code from .onInit, it can force Swedish. If you want NSIS to pick the best language, remove all code from .onInit.

Comment: Ok, If i remove the code from .OnInit, Can i use     System::Call 'kernel32::GetUserDefaultUILanguage() i.r10'   to get the default system locale?

Comment: And also is it correct to load the .nsh files like as shown below:                   !include "E:\prakash\LangTesting\LanguageFiles\English.nsh"
  !include "E:\prakash\LangTesting\LanguageFiles\Swedish.nsh"

Comment: Please help me to understand the below code:  
                                              Function mycustompage
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(mypagetitle) $(mypagesubtitle)
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u "$(defaulttext)"
    Pop $TextHandle
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd                          what is nsDialogs::Create 1018?                     And also what is ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u "$(defaulttext)"?

Comment: 1) No, don't call GetUserDefaultUILanguage. 2) Yes. 3) nsDialogs::Create 1018 creates the custom page. ${NSD_CreateText} creates the text control on that page. Read the nsDialogs documentation...